# Wait for Button Press in Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

I'm developing a calculator app and would like to add 10 storage registers that the User can store numbers to.  The calculator's storyboard has a "STO" button that is pressed when the User wants to store an entry.  The next numeric button pressed (button 0, button 1 ... button 9) would signify the register to store the entry in.

The app currently contains the method "STOButtonPressed":

```
 - (IBAction)STOButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{

    STOButtonPressed = YES;

    }
```

I have a method for entering numbers into the calculator, called digitPressed:

```
  - (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender{

            NSString* digit = sender.currentTitle;
            [_audioPlayer play];

            if(!(self.dotNotation && [digit isEqualToString:@"."])){

                if([digit isEqualToString:@"."])
                    self.dotNotation=YES;

                if(self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping){
                    self.displayLabel.text = [self.displayLabel.text stringByAppendingString:digit];

                }
                else
                {
                    self.displayLabel.text = digit;
                    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = YES;
                }
            }

    }
```

Each number button on the calculator in the storyboard is tagged (button "0" is tag "0", button "1" is tag "1", etc....).

After pressing the "STO" button, I'd like the next button (0 thru 9) entry to be the storage register number.  And I'd like to set the storage register number within the STOButtonPressed method.  Not sure if that's possible, or how to do it if it is.  I currently have several "IF statements" in the digitPressed method for determining the storage register number (not shown here).  But that seems very cumbersome and the method has gotten very messy.  I'd like to keep all code for the storage feature within the STOButtonPressed method.  I've been working this unsuccessfully for many days, and feel I'm missing something.  Can someone tell me how to make set the storage register number within the STOButtonPressed method, if that's even possible?

I'm using Xcode 5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I did implement something similar to your "else if //store stuff here" suggestion, but my code wasn't quite as elegant.  However, I'd really like to keep all of the code for the storage feature within the STOButtonPressed method, as the digitPressed function has gotten very long due to the trig, power, sq root, etc features also being implemented in the app.  Is there any way in the STOButtonPressed method to pause and wait for a # button press, or loop until a # button is pressed?  Don't think there is, but need to ask those more familiar with Objective C than me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set your button's tags properly, it should be pretty straightforward:

in your properties, add:

```
   @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hasPressedSTOButton;
```

and change this because you don't want confusion between your var and your method name:

```
- (IBAction)STOButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{

        self.hasPressedSTOButton = YES;

    }
```

And change your tags to 1-10 instead of 0-9 because you want to make sure you are checking a button with a non-zero tag, and not some other button.

then change your digitPressed like this

```
  - (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender{

            NSString* digit = sender.currentTitle;
            [_audioPlayer play];

            if(!(self.dotNotation && [digit isEqualToString:@"."])){

                if([digit isEqualToString:@"."])
                    self.dotNotation=YES;

                if(self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping){
                    self.displayLabel.text = [self.displayLabel.text stringByAppendingString:digit];

                }
                else
                {
                    self.displayLabel.text = digit;
                    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = YES;
                }
            } else if (sender.tag != 0) {
                //store your stuff here.  Tags range from 1 to 10.  Use sender.tag - 1 if you want the values to range from 0 to 9.    
            }

    }
```